# iOS: Incoming Calls - show company name on all calls from any extension number (wildcard?)

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

what i do:

- i save a contact and they have an extension number +49/030/12345-678 - here is the company head number 12345 - the 12345-0 would normaly the company reception and many extension numbers

what i see:

- when someone calls me from a different extension number -> it shows unknown caller

what i expect:

- i like to save it somehow that also calls from different extension number show me at least the company name

Note:

- on an old nokia it was possible to save the head number 12345 and it shows the company. name
- i know there are some Spam Blocking Apps with wildcard support - but in my use case i don't like to block this calls - i need just an info
- Bonus Poinst: when i can setup this functionality just with the contacts app and not need to type it into an external app twice